# Matrix image regression or regression of subscales

Tags: regression, matrix

A person is given 10 sample images (based on the same image) with corresponding techniques on how the image was achieved. I want to regress the matrix bitmap of the image of the 10 images on the image created by the person as a gross way of knowing which images the person copied from. I am assuming that if the person copied one particular person, they will have more corresponding pixels than other people.

Is there such a thing as matrix regression? Can anyone point me to other possible techniques?

I also have a rating scale of the features present in each image. With a similar intent, I would like to regress the subscores of the rating scale of the sample images to the subscore of the particular person's image. I imagine the same regression technique could be used.

Hoping someone out there can point me to a technique that would let me do this.

Comment: While I haven't heard of *matrix regression* I have heard of *principal component regression* and of *2D principal component analysis*. I guess you could easily calculate scores from the 2D PCA on your images to reduce the dimensionality of your sample greatly. Then analyzing those PC score vectors instead of your original image would be straight-forward and easy to achieve even with standard univariate techniques as those score vectors would be orthogonal to each other.

Comment: Why can't you just use each pixel and channel as a coordinate in ordinary least squares?  For example, with a 2x2 image, you'd have a length 12 vector of independent variables: pixel 11 R; pixel 11 G; pixel 11 B; pixel 12 R;...... pixel 22 G; pixel 22 B

Comment: Anyhow, if you're not concerned about literal individual pixels, but about "broad features", then you should use a convolutional neutal network.  These have been state-of-the-art in image regression/classification for a decade now.  Probably you could do some kind of very naive similarity comparison of the activations (e.g. the norm of the difference) at an arbitrary depth of, say, VGGNet between two images to get a "similar techniques" metric.

Answer (score 0):

One image becomes another, different image by a transformation.  There are a large number of transformations possible.  They are in fact infinite given they are real valued.  There are a large number of general forms.

You could add a constant.  That would displace the intensities.
You could translate in x and y.
You could rotate.  Although it is a 2d image you can treat the intensities as heights and thus treat the image as a surface in 3-space.  You can then rotate it on any of the 3 axes.
These are "rigid" transforms.  You could bend or warp the image in any number of ways.

For some convenient and intuitive transforms I like to use 3d homogenous affine transforms. In the homogenous transform there is an additional dimension whose coordinates are unity.  This allows translations to work easier.

I have a presentation on the topic of bottom-up exploration of transformations.  If there was a way to make it accessible on the internet, I would like to do that.

Bottom line: 3d homogenous affine transforms might do very well.  You can treat it like a least squares problem with pseudo-inverse solution.

Comment: I might not have made my question clear. You're right that there are many transformations that could change one picture to another and for that reason my regression would be very noisy. Nonetheless, I would like to treat each pixel as a data point and compare it to the corresponding data point via a regression. The images were created by trying to copy a model image. Any idea how to do this regression?

Comment: Yes.  There are a couple of ways to do this, but the simplest is this: Turn your original  and transformed image into vectors.  [X-loc, Y-loc, Z-loc, ones].   Formulate this as a least squares, that is, multiply the transformed array by the pseudo-inverse of the original array.  This should give you a 4x4 matrix whose coefficients indicate translation, rotation, scaling, and offsets.

Comment: That sounds like it's heading in the right direction. What I'm really trying to ask is which of 5 images best predicts a final image. So for example, if the final image was identical to one of the images, that image should suck up all the variance and the other 4 get none. If it's a combination of two images, those would share the variance and the other 3 get none, or it could be a combination of multiple images with different relative contributions. Any thoughts on that?

Thanks for your help, btw.